# Why is this python code not thread-safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, concurrency

I handed this in as part a school assignment and the person who marked it mentioned that this section was not thread safe.

The assignment was to create a multithreaded socket server in python that accepted a number and returned the Fibonacci value of that number. My approach was to memoize the calculations by sharing a dictionary between each of the threads.

Here is the code (with error handling and such removed for brevity)

```
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer, BaseRequestHandler


class FibonacciThreadedTCPServer(ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer):
    def __init__(self, server_address):
        TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, FibonacciThreadedTCPRequestHandler, bind_and_activate=True)
        #this dictionary will be shared between all Request handlers
        self.fib_dict = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1}


class FibonacciThreadedTCPRequestHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        num = int(data)
        result = self.calc_fib(self.server.fib_dict, num)
        ret = bytes(str(result) + '\n', 'ascii')
        self.request.sendall(ret)


    @staticmethod
    def calc_fib(fib_dict, n):
        """
        Calculates the fibonacci value of n using a shared lookup table and a linear calculation.
        """
        length = len(fib_dict)
        while length <= n:
            fib_dict[length] = fib_dict[length - 1] + fib_dict[length - 2]
            length = len(fib_dict)
        return fib_dict[n]
```

I understand that there are reads and writes occuring simultaneously in the calc_fib method, and normally that means that code is not thread-safe. However in this instance I think it's possible to prove that the code will always provide predictable results.

Is the fact that reads and writes can be occuring simultaneously enough for it to not be considered thread-safe? Or is something considered thread-safe if it always returns a reliabel result.

Why I think this code will always produce reliable results:

1. A read will never occur on any given index in the dictionary until a write has occurred there.
2. Any subsequent writes to any given index will contain the same number as the previous writes, so regardless of when the read/write sequence occurs it will always receive the same data.

I have tested this by added random sleeps between each operation and making requests with several hundred threads simultaneously and the right answer is already returned during my test.

Any thoughts or criticism would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What did your marker person say when you asked them about this?

Comment: We have an option in this class to have our assignments marked anonomously by professionals who work at local companies. Unfortunately I can't ask the person who marked it without going through the proxy of my teacher. I was hoping to get some info from the StackOverflow community first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case, [the GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GIL) should keep your code safe, because:

1. CPython built-in data structures are protected from actual damage (as opposed to merely incorrect behavior) by the GIL (`dict` in particular *needs* this guarantee, because class instances and non-local scope usually use `dict`s for attribute/name lookup, and without the GIL, simply reading the values would be fraught with danger)
2. You're updating a cached value of the length then using it for the next set of operations instead of rechecking the length during the mutation; this can lead to repeated work (multiple threads see the old length and compute the new value repeatedly) but since the key is always set to the same value, it doesn't matter if they each set it independently
3. You never delete from your cache (if you did, that cached length would bite you)

So in CPython, this should be fine. I can't make any guarantees for other Python interpreters though; without the GIL, if they implement their `dict` without internal locking, it's wholly possible a rehash operation triggered by a write in one thread could cause another thread to read from a `dict` in an inconsistent/unusable state.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I attempted to delve into the complexities of the GIL while I was working on the assignment to try ensuring my code would be safe. I am just learning about concurrency in school now in my standard courses so I am still a little shakey. 

As far as terminology goes would you say that I am being thread-safe. Or would you say that I am making a safe operation in a non thread-safe way. 

Thinking I was being clever in my assignment I explicitly stated that the calc_fib method was thread-safe :P. I am trying to decide if it's worth it to argue for marks

Comment: @M.Wallace: Well, if you ran this in, say, Jython, there is no guarantee (from the Python spec anyway) it wouldn't crash and burn. Python the language spec doesn't say whether this is safe, CPython the specific interpreter says it's safe. So it depends on what sort of interpreter guarantees you can make. With stuff like C++, equivalent code wouldn't even be able to say you could safely _read_ the length of the structure (you could read partially written values); in theory there might be some valid Python interpreter out there that might show you a partially written lengths.

Comment: Short version: If you're just learning, try not to grow too dependent on GIL guarantees and lock your accesses properly. Getting Python's threading guarantees ingrained early on will hurt you, badly, when you eventually learn lower level languages that laugh at the idea that reads on one thread need reflect some sequentially consistent view of the data as written by another thread.

Comment: Thanks again for the answers. I did realize while writing it that it was a bit of an ugly magic trick. For some reason I thought that having a server that could serve a hundred requests of Fib(30000) at the same time would be better than actually writing it with proper locking. I had actually originally written it with thread locking and changed it thinking I was being clever doing it this way and trying to speed up the code.

Comment: @M.Wallace: Well, the extra trick here is that the GIL means all that threading doesn't actually get you parallel computational power. Only one thread executing byte code means your threads are mostly about parallelizing the I/O; the odds of two threads hitting the lock at the same time after the first few requests are pretty small, since the lock owner would have to be stripped of the GIL mid-update (and the work between I/Os is small enough that they probably keep the GIL for the whole of the method). So using the lock is unlikely to hurt much if at all.

Comment: so if I'm reading that correctly, you are saying that adding a lock won't actually add much overhead since the chances are that two threads won't be hitting the computational part of the work that is locked at the same time?

Comment: @M.Wallace: Yup. Locks that aren't under contention are fairly cheap to acquire/release, and the GIL reduces the odds of contention (the GIL itself may be under contention), so the incremental cost of adding the lock is likely to be small.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why do you think that dictionaries are thread-safe?  I did a quick search of Python3 documentation (I'm a Python novice myself), and I can not find any reassurance that two unsynchronized threads can safely update the same dictionary without corrupting the dictionary internals and maybe crashing the program.

I've been writing multi-threaded code in other languages since 1980-something, and I've learned never to trust that something is thread safe just because it acts that way when I test it.  I want to see documentation that it's *supposed* to be thread safe.  Otherwise, I throw a mutex around it.

Second of all, you are assuming that `fib_dict[length - 1]` and `fib_dict[length - 2]` will be valid.  My experience with other programming languages says not to assume it.  In other programming languages, (e.g., Java), when threads share data without synchronization, it is possible for one thread to see variable updates happen in a different order from the order in which some other thread performed them.  E.g., it is theoretically possible for a Java thread that accesses a `Map` with no synchronization to see the `size()` of the `Map` increase before it sees the new values actually appear *in* the map.  I will assume that something similar could happen in Python until somebody shows me official documentation that says otherwise.

Comment: As a rule, CPython makes a fairly strong effort to avoid thread races corrupting data structures; beyond protecting reference counts, [the GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GIL) protects stuff like `dict` so it doesn't suffer from issues that would crash the program. You might get the wrong data in some circumstances (e.g. `mydict[foo] += 1` could lose increments when performed in multiple threads), but it shouldn't crash.

Comment: Because of the GIL in CPython, Python dict lookups and assignments (with instances of builtin types as the key) are threadsafe. Using custom class instances as keys may not be safe, since the thread running a pure Python `__hash__` method can be paused between bytecodes to let another thread run. But builtin types (like `int`) have their `__hash__` computed purely in C code, which can't be interrupted. I'm pretty sure the GIL's synchronization also prevents the out of order updates you mention in your second point (but I'm less sure of that).

Comment: I was operating under the assumption that due to the GIL all reads would be valid (either taking place before or after the write). Since in my use case any write is simply putting the same data into a cell that already had that data no race condition is created. I am having trouble finding any official documentation to backup this assumption though. I also see that assumption of the GIL is a bad practice since it is not actually part of python just part of the CPython interpreter. I would still appreciate if someone could provide more insight on whether what I did could be considered safe.

Comment: @Blckknght: It's not just `__hash__` BTW; collision resolution can invoke `__eq__` as well, and that can cause issues as well (though less frequently, since the two objects would only invoke `__eq__` if they had the exact same hash and weren't the same object). That said, it's usually pretty pathological cases where that matters; in this case, even if `int` performed `__hash__` or `__eq__` in byte code, the operation ordering should protect you from anything weird. Stuff like `dict.setdefault` has had issues w/non-builtin keys making it behave non-atomically, so it's something to keep in mind.